# Errors during compilation of C code

Tags: c, arrays

I am having a few issues with this code. I have included the errors at the end of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
void addition(double number1, double number2); /* create the functions */
void subtraction(double number1, double number2);
void division(double number1, double number2);
void multiplication(double number1, double number2);
int inputfunc=1;
double inputnum1=0;
double inputnum2=0;
int number1;
int number2;
int answer;

while (inputfunc >= 1 && inputfunc <= 4) /* If function to be performed are those   below then continue performing loop */

{
printf("Press 1 to add two numbers.\n");
printf("Press 2 to subtract two numbers.\n");
printf("Press 3 to multiply two numbers.\n");
printf("Press 4 to divide two numbers.\n");
printf("Press 5 to exit.\n");
printf("Enter your choice\n");
scanf_s("%d", &inputfunc);

if( inputfunc == 5) /* Exit program if requested via 5 function */
return(0);

printf("Enter both numbers with a space in between.");
scanf_s("%lf %lf", &inputnum1, &inputnum2);

void(*func[4])(double, double)={&addition, &subtraction, &division, &multiplication};
  (*func[inputfunc-1])(inputnum1, inputnum2); 
  return(0);
  }

}

void addition(double number1, double number2) 
{
  double answer; 
  answer=number1+number2;
  printf("Addition of the two numbers = %lf + %lf = %lf\n", number1, number2, answer); 
  return;
} 

void subtraction(double number1, double number2)
{ 
  double answer; 
  answer=number1-number2;
  printf("By subtracting the two numbers results are %lf - %lf = %lf\n", number1,
    number2, answer); 
  return;
} 

void multiplication(double number1, double number2) 
{ 
  double answer; 
  answer=number1*number2;
  printf("By multiplying the two numbers results are %lf * %lf = %lf\n", number1, 
      number2, answer); 
  return;
} 

void division(double number1, double number2) 
{ 
  double answer; 
  answer=number1/number2;
  printf("By dividing the two numbers results are %lf / %lf = %lf\n", number1, 
        number2,  answer); 
  return ;
}
```

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
>   error C2065: 'func' : undeclared identifier
>   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: Please, indent your code, because mistakes like these are happening if you write the code with your feet.

Comment: Hilarious :-)  Btw, @DonCarter, could you please upvote those who helped you? It is standard practise, not only to reward them, but to indicate to others with the same problem what actually solved it. You can upvote and also accept one answer,

Comment: Unlike some UniCell, I was not born with the ability to write code. The code I posted was a copy and paste from Word which doesn't always transpose as it is written. You should have more patience with beginners. I have only been at this for three weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Over the line i have posted below from your code, You are ending the main method with the second brace.
That is not a very good idea, as you have code below that brace.

```
void(*func[4])(double, double)={&addition, &subtraction, &division, &multiplication};
(*func[inputfunc-1])(inputnum1, inputnum2); 
return(0);
} //end while

}  //end main method
```

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles and works - see [it in action here](http://ideone.com/dHwSWI)

Some points:

- This is C code, not C#
- The `return(0);` is placed within the `while` loop - this will prevent it from asking the user for more than one run. Move this below the end of the `while` loop.
- The declaration of the array holding the various function pointers to the arithmetic operators should not be positioned within the while loop - it doesn't change between each iteration - i.e. move `void(*func[4])(double, double) = { &addition, &subtraction, &division, &multiplication };` to above the `while`
- Better indentation will make the code more readable
- The topmost declarations of `int number1;    int number2;    int answer;` are redundant and should be removed (especially as these are used as local variable names with different types in the 4 arithmetic functions).

I've made the above changes to the snippet (`scanf_s` was replaced with simple `scanf` as IdeOne doesn't use the MS Compiler).

Answer (score -1):

```
// the scanf_s function is the secure function for string input, using scanf

// this version compiles without any warnings, etc under linux gcc

// this version checks for input errors 
// (except the actual value of the variable inputFunc)
// I think the use of a switch() statement would be much more robust
// rather than the use of the function ptr table, although not quite as flexable

// Notice the function prototypes are outside of any function
// so the compiler will create the proper code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // contains exit() and EXIT_FAILURE

// function prototypes
void addition(double number1, double number2);
void subtraction(double number1, double number2);
void division(double number1, double number2);
void multiplication(double number1, double number2);


void(*func[4])(double, double)={&addition, &subtraction, &division, &multiplication};

int main()
{

    int inputFunc=1;
    double inputnum1=0;
    double inputnum2=0;

    /* If function to be performed are those   
       below then continue performing loop */

    // note:
    // if the inputFunc is (for instance) 6 then this while loop is exited
    // however, there was no return statement
    // for that execution path

    while (inputFunc >= 1 && inputFunc <= 4) 
    {
        printf("Press 1 to add two numbers.\n");
        printf("Press 2 to subtract two numbers.\n");
        printf("Press 3 to multiply two numbers.\n");
        printf("Press 4 to divide two numbers.\n");
        printf("Press 5 to exit.\n");
        printf("Enter your choice\n");

        if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &inputFunc) )
        {
            perror( "scanf_s" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE ) ;
        }

        // implied else, scanf for which command was successful

        // note: there should be some checking here 
        //       to assure that the input was in the valid range '1...5'

        if( inputFunc == 5)
        { /* then, Exit while loop if requested via 5 function */
          // note: good program practice is to put the return
          //       at the bottom of the function
             break;
        }

        printf("Enter both numbers with a space in between.");
        if( 2 != scanf(" %lf %lf", &inputnum1, &inputnum2) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for 2 input numbers" );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // implied else, scanf for two input numbers successful

        // exec the desired function
        (*func[inputFunc-1])(inputnum1, inputnum2);
    }
    return(0); // to avoid compiler warning
}

void addition(double number1, double number2)
{
  double answer;
  answer=number1+number2;
  printf("Addition of the two numbers = %lf + %lf = %lf\n", number1, number2, answer);
  return;
}

void subtraction(double number1, double number2)
{
    double answer;
    answer=number1-number2;
    printf("By subtracting the two numbers results are %lf - %lf = %lf\n",
        number1,
        number2,
        answer);
}

void multiplication(double number1, double number2)
{
    double answer;
    answer=number1*number2;
    printf("By multiplying the two numbers results are %lf * %lf = %lf\n",
        number1,
        number2,
        answer);
}

void division(double number1, double number2)
{
    // note:  this should check that number2 is NOT 0, to avoid divide by zero error
    double answer;
    answer=number1/number2;
    printf("By dividing the two numbers results are %lf / %lf = %lf\n",
        number1,
        number2,
        answer);
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, Thanks to you and everyone else for the input. I have and will continue to read your replies so I can avoid future errors of this nature. Thanks again!